# How do I know what type of variable to use for an instance of an object?

Tags: java, instances

```
package RPG;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Beginnings
{
    public static boid main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Pick a class:");
        System.out.println("Fighter: Deals more damage");
        System.out.println("Mage: Has more health");
        System.out.println("Theif: Deals less damage but has         more health");
        String Class = scan.nextLine();
        if (Class.matches(".*Fighter.*"));
            Fighter user = new Fighter();
        else if (Class.matches(".*Mage.*"));
            Mage user = new Mage();
        else if (Class.matches(".*Thief.*"));
            Thief user = new Thief();
        else
            Human user = new Human();
        user.Name();
        user.Explore();
```

/*When I run the code, it highlights the first "user" and says "variable declaration not allowed here" 
 I don't know how to fix this. 
*/

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I believe you cannot declare variables inside `if` statements, which would also be included for `if else` statements.

Comment: Your `if` statements won't work as you intend, either, given you have semicolons immediately after the conditions.

Comment: What should i do instead of having the semicolons immediately after the condition?

Comment: I would suggest you learn about interfaces, declare `user` as an interface type and assign it as `new ` _whatever_ `()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a few spelling mistakes that might be causing problems

```
public static boid main (String[] args)
```

should be

```
public static void main (String[] args)
```

and

```
System.out.println("Theif: Deals less damage but has         more health");
```

should probably be

```
System.out.println("Thief: Deals less damage but has         more health");
```

Futhermore, capital case `Class()` and lowercase `class` are already things in the Java SDK as well. You should use a different variable name. I've used `characterStr` in my example below. Standard practice dictates that you should use camelcase for naming variables and upper case for naming Java classes. When instantiating a `Class()` object, people generally instantiate it as `Class clazz = new Class()`.

Moving forward, I think you should create a super class for your different User Classes. Set up something like this:

```
public abstract class Character
public class Fighter extends Character
public class Thief extends Character
public class Mage extends Character
public class Human extends Character
```

This way, the code in your `main()` can use your `Character()` object

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Prompt the user for the character they want
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Pick a class:");
    System.out.println("Fighter: Deals more damage");
    System.out.println("Mage: Has more health");
    System.out.println("Theif: Deals less damage but has         more health");

    // Get the user's response
    String characterStr = scan.nextLine();

    Character user; // You might have to initialize this. Did not test
    if (characterStr.matches(".*Fighter.*"))
    {
        user = new Fighter();
    }
    else if (characterStr.matches(".*Mage.*"));
    { 
        user = new Mage();
    }        
    else if (characterStr.matches(".*Thief.*"));
    {
        user = new Thief();
    }
    else
    {
        user = new Human();
    }

    user.Name();
    user.Explore();

}
```

Comment: No need to instanciate a _generic_ `Character` at the beginning. I would even recommand `Character` to be `abstract`. Also you should use a standard syntax for `if (...) { ... } else if (...) { ...}` with braces around the block statements for readability.

Comment: Thank you SO much j.seashell.

Comment: @AbbéRésina edited. I just copied the original content but I agree, it's much easier to read without the single-line syntax

Comment: @NickPark lemme get dat "Answered" tag doe :D

Answer (score 1):

First problem : You cannot declare a variable in the `then` of the `if` statement if you don't put the declaration between parenthesis. The compiler doesn't accept it.

Second problem : you should declare a single variable before the `if-else-if` if you want at the end call a method on the instantiated instance as you do :

```
user.Name();
user.Explore();
```

In each `if` you should instantiate the suitable child User class and assign the it to the `user` variable declared above.

In Java, method should begin with lowercase. I modified it.
The code supposes that `User` is the parent class and class you instantiate in condition statements are subclasses of `User`.
`User` should define a `name()` method and a `explore()` method.

```
    User user = null;
    if (Class.matches(".*Fighter.*")){
         user = new Fighter();
    }
    else if (Class.matches(".*Mage.*")){
         user = new Mage();
    }
    else if (Class.matches(".*Thief.*")){
         user = new Thief();
    }
    else{
         user = new Human();
    }
    user.name();
    user.explore();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 'user' is a player who has a 'class' (ie fighter / mage). I would make a separate player class and store that information.

```
class Player {

  String classType; // where you would store the player's class information

  int hitPoints;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of the variable has to be a common base class of all objects you potentially assign to it. Since the class `Object` is a base class of all other classes, you could do this:

```
Object user = new Fighter();
```

But it is probably not a good idea.

You should probably derive `Fighter`, `Mage` etc. from a base class, say `Character`. Instead of a base class you can also use an interface.